# Using subdate and max(date) in a subquery

Tags: mysql, date, subquery, aggregate-functions

I tried this query and got error. The sub query alone returns the desired result.

```
Select * 
from usi 
where present_date = select subdate(MAX(present_date), 1) AS PreviousDate from usi
```

What am I not doing correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need parentheses around a subquery:

```
Select * 
from usi 
where present_date = (select subdate(MAX(present_date), 1) AS PreviousDate from usi);
```

As a note:  `subdate()` -- while completely valid -- looks strange.  I'm more used to seeing `date_sub()` or `- interval 1 day`.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Your solution did not give error yet it did not retrieve any record as expected. Both date_sub and interval 1 day give error. I don't know why.

Comment: Now this is wierd. I have been working on my local phpmyadmin. I just tried your query on live (phpmyadmin version 3.5.8.2 and it worked perfectly while local phpmyadmin version 4.4.14 still retrieves no row. What could be happening?

Comment: @Gyne . . . I would guess that the data is different between the two systems.  Even if the data looks the same, you need be be careful, because `present_date` could have a time component.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I dropped my local table and imported production. Now everything works fine including DATE_SUB(MAX(present_date) , interval 1 DAY